# I can't write javascript code at js.file in visual studio 2012

Tags: javascript

When I try to write javascript code in js.file.I get some errors.How to solve this issue ?

```
class CommentBox extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="commentBox">Hello.</div>
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<CommentBox />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is JSX, not plain JavaScript

Comment: How can I do.I can't find jsx file in items.

Comment: VS 2012 doesn't support JSX (though there seems to be an plugin: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/31b07819-6a40-4069-955a-1f63c76def65/how-to-add-and-use-react-js-in-visual-studio-2012?forum=visualstudiogeneral) You should probably upgrade to a newer Visual Studio version

Comment: Thanks.Also I try to write js(not jsx) again I get errors.Example,I am writing 'class'.Text's underline becoming red.

Comment: The `class` syntax is part of ES2015, which came out way later than VS2012

Comment: thank you for your effort. am going to download vs2015.It will be for the best probably